# Upload files to One Drive using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, onedrive

I am following below to upload files to onedrive using powershell. 
http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/07/using-the-windows-live-apis-from-powershell/

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Put -InFile $Path
```

where is a full path to a file

```
$Path= "C:\SkyDrive/ServerBackups/Webs/Webs/test.txt"
```

and 
`$Uri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?code=XXXXXX`

throws a (404) Not found error.

Comment: Could you post your full code so we can see what $Uri and $Path are equal to, your link uses different variable names to these.

Comment: @Bluecakes I am not using a different $Uri. Edited the question. Added both $Uri & $Path.

Comment: Are you absolutely confident that $Uri contains that URL? Also, is your firewall allowing HTTPS? This URL gives me HTTP 200 regardless if I submit a valid code or not. HTTP 404 suggests that the URL is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't PUT a file to the OAuth endpoint... A quick scan of the referenced article suggests you should be using a $Uri value that looks more like $wlApiUri. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659726.aspx for a description of the URL scheme for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 3):

The value of $Uri used in the `Invoke-RestMethod` is wrong. The OAuth endpoint you used in your script is for authentication rather than OneDrive operation.

About how to upload file to OneDrive, this can be split into three parts.

1. [Register](https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm) OneDrive application for OAuth authentication process
2. Call OneDrive [authentication API](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm) to get access token
3. Use access token to call OneDrive API so as to upload file

After you created your OneDrive application, you can get **Application Id**, **secret key** and **redirect Uri** if the application is web type. Then use the script below with the three value.

```
# get authorize code
Function Get-AuthroizeCode
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$ClientId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$RedirectURI
    )
    # the login url
    $loginUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=$ClientId&scope=onedrive.readwrite offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$RedirectURI";

    # open ie to do authentication
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.Navigate2($loginUrl) | Out-Null
    $ie.Visible = $True

    While($ie.Busy -Or -Not $ie.LocationURL.StartsWith($RedirectURI)) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }

    # get authorizeCode
    $authorizeCode = $ie.LocationURL.SubString($ie.LocationURL.IndexOf("=") + 1).Trim();
    $ie.Quit() | Out-Null

    RETURN $authorizeCode
}

# get access token and refresh token
Function New-AccessTokenAndRefreshToken
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$ClientId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$RedirectURI,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$SecrectKey
    )
    # get authorize code firstly
    $AuthorizeCode = Get-AuthroizeCode -ClientId $ClientId -RedirectURI $RedirectURI

    $redeemURI = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf"
    $header = @{"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    $postBody = "client_id=$ClientId&redirect_uri=$RedirectURI&client_secret=$SecrectKey&code=$AuthorizeCode&grant_type=authorization_code"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Method Post -Uri $redeemURI -Body $postBody

    $AccessRefreshToken = New-Object PSObject
    $AccessRefreshToken | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name AccessToken -Value $response.access_token
    $AccessRefreshToken | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name RefreshToken -Value $response.refresh_token

    RETURN $AccessRefreshToken
}
```

Then you get your valid access token, you can build valid header for `Invoke-RestMethod`

```
# get autheticate header
Function Get-AuthenticateHeader
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$AccessToken
    )

    RETURN @{"Authorization" = "bearer $AccessToken"}
}
```

Finally, you can pass the header to `Invoke-RestMethod` with upload rest api.

There have four different OneDrive upload rest Api you can call.

1. [Simple item upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm)
2. [Resumable item upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm)
3. [Multipart item upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_post.htm)
4. [Upload from Url](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_url.htm)

If your target file is not too big, means the length of the file is within 100MB, I highly recommend to use [Simple item upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm).

For big file, it is common to call [Resumable item upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm) API

It is a big story, you can refer to this [upload file to OneDrive sample](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-upload-large-file-1c5c2e6c) for the complete script directly.

Hopefully you can get rid of the problem.

Comment: I need to upload file to OneDrive with PowerShell and do not have a real web application page. How should I create redirect Uri for my case?